# Show context menu on imagegridview

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a context menu that popsup when I hold my finger (long) on an image in a gridview.

Now In the fragment that creates the gridview I've did this:

OnCreate:

```
imageGrid.setAdapter(ImageAdapter);
```

Where ImageAdapter is my seperate class that does the work for me.

Also in the same fragment I've got

```
 @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getTitle()=="Action1"){
            Log.d("Debug","Clicked");
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");
    }
```

Then in my adapter class I registered the longOnclickListener like this:

```
private class selectOnLongClickListener implements View.OnLongClickListener{
    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;

private selectOnLongClickListener(ViewHolder viewHolder)
{
    mViewHolder = viewHolder;
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v)
{
    Log.d("Debug","OnLongClick");
    return true;
}

}
```

The listener works, he prints me the debug output when I hold my finger long on an image. But the context menu never shows. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Register your GridView For ContextMenu inside`OnCreate()`.

like this

```
registerForContextMenu(imageGrid);
```

then call like this

**Edit :**

```
 @Override
 public boolean onLongClick(View v)
{
    Log.d("Debug", "OnLongClick");
    v.showContextMenu();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the OnItemLongClickListener can't be resolved because I'm extending from Fragment.

Comment: Try with `v.showContextMenu();` inside `onLongClick()`

Answer (score 0):

Do u try call this in your activity

```
this.openContextMenu(...);

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v)
{
    Log.d("Debug","OnLongClick");

    YourActivity.this.openContextMenu(v);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm working with fragments, do I need to do getActivity().this.openContextMenu(v)?

Comment: yeah, that's it, getActivity().openContextMenu(v)

Comment: I can't use that because my adapter class extends from baseAdapter so I can't use getActivity().

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `grid.setOnItemLongClickListener(listener);`

Answer (score 0):

This is the modified listener.

```
private class selectOnLongClickListener implements View.OnLongClickListener{
    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;

    private selectOnLongClickListener(ViewHolder viewHolder)
    {
        mViewHolder = viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
        Log.d("Debug", "OnLongClick");
        v.showContextMenu();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The v.showContextMenu() does the trick.